# "Poster presentation" vs "poster only" in academic conference

Tags: conference, presentation, poster, workshop

I want to submit an abstract. I have three options:

1. Oral presentation
2. Poster presentation
3. Poster ONLY

What is the difference between 2 and 3?

Comment: In the 3rd option, it seems you just send your poster there but not be present in poster session by yourself. I have done that once as poster presentation was not supported by institution and I did not have the means to go there, but check carefully the conference you are about to submit your abstract.

Comment: Your choice depends on the question why you want to submit an abstract there.

Comment: Some conferences select a small number of poster presenters to give a more traditional (albeit short) slide-based talk in a special session.  So, you either present just a poster (if your abstract is not selected), or you present the poster _and_ a short talk.

Answer (score 6):

A poster presentation generally means that before the poster session you get a short (~3 min) slot to summarise your poster to the audience.

A poster session (poster only) implies that you only want to display your poster, not speak about it to the audience (you should still stand near your poster to answer people's questions about it as they walk around).

Comment: Thank you. A poster presentation is preceded by a pitch and then answering the questions during the poster session? or you answer the question after the 3 min presentation and you don't have to stand near the poster during the poster session?

Comment: I would probably stand near the poster anyway because you can get into a proper conversation rather than limiting yourself to a Q and A sessoom.